# Upload image to firebase and set a link in database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I know how to add data to the firebase database, I know how to upload image to the firebase storage. I am doing this in javascript.

I am not able to figure out how to link the image to my database object.

My database object is something like this

```
{
name:'alex',
age:23,
profession:'superhero'
image:*what to put here ???*
}
```

One idea is to use the object reference that is created and store the image using the same reference.

Any tutorial or ideas appreciated.

Comment: Use Functions to write the link to the DB when the image finishes uploading to Storage. Or follow the example and just do a db write when PutFileAsync() completes. What's the question here? What have you tried? What platform?

Comment: FYI - The last example on [this codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#7) demonstrates uploading an image and storing results in DB. there's also web/ios versions.

Answer (score 2):

We often recommend storing the `gs://bucket/path/to/object` reference, otherwise store the `https://...` URL.

See [Zero to App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE) and it's associated [source code](https://gist.github.com/puf/8f67d3376d80ed2d02670d20bfc4ec7d#file-index-html-L88) (here we use the `https://...` version) for a practical example.

Comment: Portability and security. Any Storage client (Firebase or Google Cloud Storage) can create a download URL from a gs URI, while at present, the https URLs are more Firebase specific. Additionally, the https URLs are publicly accessible, while the gs URIs require security rules or IAM checks to retrieve download URLs or content.

Answer (score 0):

```
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('some/storage/bucket');
var saveDataRef = firebase.database().ref('users/');
var uploadTask = storageRef.put(file);

uploadTask.on('state_changed', uploadTick, (err)=> {
  console.log('Upload error:', err);
}, ()=> {
  saveDataRef.update({
    name:'alex',
    age:23,
    profession:'superhero'
    image:uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL
  });
});
```

This upload function sits inside a ES6 class and is passed a callback (uploadTick) for the .on('state_changed') from the calling component.  That way you can pass back upload status and display that in the UI.

```
uploadTick(snap){
  console.log("update ticked", snap)
  this.setState({
    bytesTransferred:snap.bytesTransferred,
    totalBytes:snap.totalBytes
   })
}
```

The file to upload is passed to this upload function, but I am just using a react form upload to get the file and doing a little processing on it, your approach may vary.